# Untrack files from git in worktree

Tags: git, repository

I have three machine, local -> Server A -> Server B
and programming on local, then use git push local code to Server A,
on Server A I set a hook to push the code to Server B,
both on Server A and Server B have configure this

```
$ git config core.worktree /home/www
$ git config core.bare false
$ git config receive.denycurrentbranch ignore
```

and have a hook `git checkout -f`

how can I change some files on Server B and not track it?

I try `git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file`
but alway notice `fatal: Unable to write new index file`

I'm sure user have permission in that folder(can write, read and execute)
I also try `git update-index --skip-worktree path/to/file` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `.gitignore` file in your repository. You can include the files which should not be tracked into `.gitignore`, read more [here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files).